# Why is namespace being changed when I use npm to install lib?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am trying to use whammy.js in a project.
The first line of source reads

```
window.Whammy = (function(){
```

but when I run npm i and look in node_modules I see

```
global.Whammy = (function(){
```

https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy/blob/master/whammy.js

```
{
...
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova": "^9.0.0",
        "react": "^16.8.5",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-actions": "^2.2.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "whammy": "0.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "del": "^4.0.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
        "gulp": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-cli": "^2.0.1",
        "gulp-jest": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
        "jest-cli": "^24.5.0",
        "jest-dom": "^3.1.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
        "react-testing-library": "^6.0.2",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
            "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": {
                "XWALK_VERSION": "21+",
                "XWALK_LITEVERSION": "xwalk_core_library_canary:17+",
                "XWALK_COMMANDLINE": "--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect",
                "XWALK_MODE": "embedded",
                "XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK": "true"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser"
        ]
    },
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "globals": {
            "cordova": {}
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "source/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "!<rootDir>/node_modules/"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
            "global": {
                "branches": 90,
                "functions": 90,
                "lines": 90,
                "statements": 90
            }
        },
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ]
    }
}
```

does anyone know what is doing this/why it's happening?
My guesses around webpack don't convince me because it's not getting to the point of using it.

Comment: Can you be more clear about, what is expected behavior or what exactly is not clear to you? The change from `window` to `global` object or the content of `package.json file`?

Comment: that npm downloads the file as the author published it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that you are trying to run npm package (which are often libs for backend) on front-end part of application. That would explain why `window`, which is global object in the browser changes after install to `global`, which is global object in Node.JS (backend).

When I look at the whammy page i see directly front-end usage (without npm install):

```
<script src="whammy.js"></script>
```

So you can probably download file directly and use it on your site like that.

Comment: `npm i` is shortcut for `npm install`

Comment: I had almost got to the point that I just put the file in my repo.
I don't see any signs of impending updates to track right now... 
but it's disappointing not to understand this.

Comment: Have you checked [Whamy GitHub page](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy)? Maybe it'll help.

Comment: yes but i can't see why the source would change, essentially in this case npm is just a task runner for git so there's no reason for anything to change, I'm sure I did something but for now I don't see what.